# Combine php array with matching index sets

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays $arrayOne, $arrayTwo

```
$arrayOne = Array (
  [0] => 2012-01-30
  [1] => 1999-04-20
  )
$arrayTwo = Array (
  [0] => new
  [1] => old
  )
```

I want to merge the arrays by data index's and give the key name so the result should go. something like

```
$new = Array (
  [0] => 
     "Date" => 2012-01-30
     "Condition" => New
  [1] => 
     "Date" => 1999-04-20
     "Condition" => Old
  )
```

I have tried

```
$newArray = array_merge($arrayOne, $arrayTwo)
```

just to combine the arrays, but this is not the format i was looking for

Comment: You might be looking for array_merge_recursive, but it will only work to combine the values of matching keys to arrays where the keys are not integers.

Comment: It might be an idea to look at how you define these variables, perhaps its easier to create the variable that way. Although I see you have a solution, there might be a more optimal alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the arrays always match in length, this will work:

```
$newArray = array();

foreach( $arrayOne as $i => $val )
{
    $newArray[] = array(
       'Date' => $val, 
       'Condition' => ucfirst($arrayTwo[$i])
    );
}
```

[**phpFiddle demo**](https://eval.in/852809)

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it this way:

```
<?php

$dates = [
    "2012-01-30",
    "1999-04-20"
];

$ages = [
    "new",
    "old"
];

$results = array_map(function($date, $age) {
    return [ "Date" => $date, "Condition" => $age ];
}, $dates, $ages);
```

Produces:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Date] => 2012-01-30
            [Condition] => new
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Date] => 1999-04-20
            [Condition] => old
        )

)
```